# 同一メソッドをtask処理で複数走らせたい時

Tags: c#, .net, マルチスレッド

お世話になります。
あるクラスのメソッドを複数taskで走らせたい時は、一度クラスをnewしたインスタンスを使い、
複数taskを走らせればよいのでしょうか？
それとも、taskごとにクラスをnewしてメソッドを使うべきでしょうか？
クラスの持つ変数の使い方や都合は一切考慮しなくてよい、単純な話になります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

何も考慮しなくて良いなら、１つのインスタンスで複数のタスクを走らせるのが単純です。

そのようなタスクだけで、実際的なアプリケーションが出来るか疑問は残ります。（まぁ、それも考慮する必要がないのでしょうが）

Comment: ありがとうございます。スレッドセーフの作りを意識して共通として使う変数は別のクラスに用意してあります。意味なく複数のインスタンスを生成する必要はなさそうですね。

Answer (score 0):

> クラスの持つ変数の使い方

通常はこの点が一番重要な判断ポイントで、MSDNなどのリファレンスで「インスタンスメンバー」が「スレッドセーフ」であるかどうかを確認して1インスタンスを使いまわすかどうかを決めます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはりインスタンスの使い方によるところなのですね